# Finding the largest value from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, element, traversal

I have to create a linked list containing 10 nodes, that each hold a double.
I then have to search this linked list for the largest value in the linked list, and display the result.
The program gets the values for each node from the user.
Below is my method of traversing the list, trying to find the largest value.

Locating the largest element. I think this is where my problem lies.

```
struct node *ptr = head;
double largest = 0.0;
while (ptr != NULL)
{
     if (ptr->val > largest)
          largest = ptr->val;

     ptr = ptr->next;
}

printf("The largest value is %lf \n", largest);
```

The program outputs: 0.0000

I have no idea why.

Comment: Have you tried stepping though/debugging it? Have you checked that `ptr` is not `null`?

Comment: Well then there's your problem. There is no list.

Comment: Algorithm looks good.

Comment: You cannot delete this question, for a reason. Please do not vandalise it. If you let me know your reason for trying to delete it I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm as-written would not work if the largest value in the list were less than 0.0.

A better solution is to define a "pointer to the largest node found," which is initially NULL.

In the loop, if this pointer's NULL, then "the first entry is always the largest so-far."  (Subsequent nodes may be found to be larger...)

If the pointer's NULL after the loop, the list must have been empty.